# Reduce FFmpeg CPU Usage with cpulimit and PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I run [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) on my server using PHP `exec()`.

It currently uses 100% of the cpu thread while encoding.

I followed [this gude](https://lorenzo.mile.si/2016/07/limiting-cpu-usage-and-server-load-with-ffmpeg/) that uses a program called [cpulimit](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit) to reduce it to 30%.

---

**PHP**

```
$args = "nice -19 cpulimit -l 30 -- ffmpeg -y -i intput.avi -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:a 192k -threads 1 output.mp4"
exec(escapeshellcmd($args));
```

FFmpeg/PHP works, and it will work with `nice`/`cpulimit` through the terminal, but after adding
 `nice -19 cpulimit -l 30 --` to the PHP script it no longer works with `exec()`.

---

**Output**

FFmpeg output returns blank. I'm not able to see the full output, I tried using:

```
$output = shell_exec($args);
echo "<p>$output</p>"
```

and

```
file_put_contents("/var/www/mysite/logs/$output.log", $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

But they return 1 empty line.

---

**Solution**

My thought is that www-data runs FFmpeg and `nice`/`cpulimit` may need root?

How can I get PHP `exec()` to work with FFmpeg args and cpulimit?

Or is there an alternative way to limit the usage %?

Comment: What's your goal in limiting the CPU usage of this process? Keep in mind that using `cpulimit` to limit the process to 30% CPU utilization will make it take ~3x longer to complete…

Comment: @duskwuff Using a server with 1 cpu and 1 thread, while using FFmpeg at 100%, wouldn't it slow down the rest of the website?

Comment: That's what `nice` is for. Reducing a process's priority with `nice` will make it "get out of the way" if other processes are running; it won't use 100% of the CPU unless nothing else needs to run.

Comment: @duskwuff What is the correct way to run nice with ffmpeg and php? When I do 'nice -19 -- ffmpeg ...' or 'nice -19 ffmpeg ...' it gives the same blank output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on this forum post using google translate.

https://murobbs.muropaketti.com/threads/nice-komento-ja-php-n-exec-funktio-ratkaistu.551174/

Define the path to FFmpeg if using `nice` or `cpulimit`

```
nice -19 cpulimit -l 30 /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ...
```

Now it works through PHP `exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

If safemode is enabled then, the execution of programes are limited. Check this documentation here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php